# how to call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions again after in app updates download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

i will like to know how do i call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions again after in app updates download, as all my function calling are in there.

i need to call this again `self.dataArray = [self readDataJsonFromDocument];`again as i download data from the net.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   


    [self   UIAppearances];    

    //first load
    [self copyJsonFromBundle];

    [self copyFolderFromBundle];

    self.dataArray = [self readDataJsonFromDocument]; //i need to call this again

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window


    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {



    //NSString *downloadFolder = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"download"];

    //save to a temp file
    NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/temp.zip", self.documentsDir];

    //download folder
    //NSString* downloadFolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/download", self.documentsDir];

    [self.fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:self.receivedData attributes:nil];

    ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    if([zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filePath]) {

//      if ([zipArchive UnzipFileTo:downloadFolder overWrite:YES]) {
        if ([zipArchive UnzipFileTo:self.documentsDir overWrite:YES]) {

            //unzipped successfully
            NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");
            [self.fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failure To Unzip Archive");             
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        }

    } else  {
        NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");
    }


    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    //Update Document File
    NSString *updateUTCPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UTCDate"];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentDate];
    [array writeToFile:updateUTCPath atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever call it manually.  That is a delegate method called by the iOS.  You need to put your calls in a separate method of their own, then call that method when you need to.

Comment: how do i do that ?, just edited my question with codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what are you trying to do?

You can certainly ***manually*** call your App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method a second time, but it would probably make more sense to put all the functionality you want to be done a second time into a separate function that gets called by **both** the delegate that's attached to your download updates method and the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: thanks, i wanna call this again self.dataArray = [self readDataJsonFromDocument]; which is inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: then set your app delegate to also be one for the code that handles downloading updates and once the update is done downloading, you can call `self.dataArray = [self readDataJsonFromDocument];` again.  Pretty straightforward.

Comment: i did it in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection delegate

Comment: could you do the `self.dataArray = [self readDataJsonFromDocument];` thing from the "successfully downloaded" part of your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method?

Answer (score 3):

You should abstract your code into another method and call that method. You shouldn't call UIApplicationDelegate methods directly.