# Swift 3 iOS10 core data check if record already exist base on id

Tags: core-data, swift3

I'm developing an app with new CoreData and Swift3 on iOS10. How do we create new object only if the id is not exist (if object already exist, we pull out object from core data and modify it only)?

Something like

```
let objectID = someNumber

If exist with objectID = someNumber {
   //modify object
}else {
   //create new object
   //assign attribute
}

//save
```

I'm trying to use the new iOS10 Swift 3 syntax for CoreData. I'm using native code not with any 3rd party library. Think of using fetch but don't know what is the proper syntax for this task.

Update: thanks to @Jan I have found the way to check. my update question a bit is to create or update entity from given JSON. Here is my function

```
static func creatOrUpdateArticle(_ json: JSON, context: NSManagedObjectContext) ->Article {

        var article: Article

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Article")
        let predicateID = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@",json[Key.id].stringValue)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicateID

        do {

            let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if results.count > 0 {
                article = results.first as! Article
            }else {
                article = Article(context: context)
            }

            article.webUrl = json[Key.webUrl].string


        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return article
    }
```

I'm getting the error: "variable article is used before being initialized". How can we make a function return an article or update existing one and return results?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I assume you know how to create a and modify an object. For the missing `exists` part, you could use something like this:

```
func someEntityExists(id: Int) -> Bool {
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "SomeEntity")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "someField = %d", id)

    var results: [NSManagedObject] = []

    do {
        results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    return results.count > 0
}
```

The new and more efficient way of doing this would be using `NSFetchRequestResult`.

```
func someEntityExists(id: Int) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SomeEntity")
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = false

    var entitiesCount = 0

    do {
        entitiesCount = try managedObjectContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    return entitiesCount > 0
}
```

Comment: thanks thinking of doing that. is the new syntax is "let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Article")" instead of fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "SomeEntity")?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh ah my apologies, I misunderstood what you want... I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have updated the question the purpose to create or update entity and return the result. can help see why there is an error

Comment: You need to declare the `article` variable with either a default value or as optional before the `do` block.

Comment: thanks work fine. what should we use: optional or default value? but it's is an coredata entity may be can not be default

Comment: May be my function is not correct. we can not return entity, we can only use completion because fetch is an asynchronous function?

Comment: I would probably use an optional because the Core Data operations can fail and get you to a situation where you just don't have anything to return.

Comment: thanks figure out my context is nil. last quest how can we inject context from appdelegate to viewcontroller (i'm using only single view application)

Comment: Check out this thread :)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705214/call-app-delegate-method-from-view-controller

Comment: mange to work. Do you think this should be a good approach or we can use something like unique constraint? The purpose is all about not create new record for existing one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147195/discussion-between-jan-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Comment: Where did you use "id" in the second example?

Comment: Maybe you forgot the predicate line in the second example, where id would be used?

Answer (score 4):

A little tip, you can rewrite the following:

```
if results.count > 0 {
    article = results.first as! Article
}else {
    article = Article(context: context)
}
```

as:

```
let article = results.first as? Article ?? Article(context: context)
```