# Use of unresolved identifier 'LaunchScreenViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I have one issues, i want to restart my app, and i have only one solution how to do it.

It's only pop to rootViewController.

My code:

```
   func restartApplication() {
    let viewController = LaunchScreenViewController()
    let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

    guard
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
        let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
        else {
            return
    }

    navCtrl.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
    navCtrl.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        window.rootViewController = navCtrl
    })

}
```

But i get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'LaunchScreenViewController'

What is the problem?

Comment: LaunchScreenViewController is available in your bundle, are you used the storyboard or xib

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes i use LaunchScreen storyboard

Comment: why you called launchscreen, call your initial VC

Comment: @Anbu.karthik because i want to reboot my app, and this only one solution

Comment: I understand, but in my suggestion is not necessary, if you need see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705214/call-app-delegate-method-from-view-controller

Comment: So you are trying to call the launchscreen storyboard. Well thats not possible because the viewcontroller which in the launchscreen storyboard does not have uiviewcontroller class associated with it.

Comment: The message is clear - you don't have a class called `LaunchScreenViewController`. Look for a typo in the class name, and check that the file containing this view controller is included in the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For xif Just replace the line of code with this ..

```
let viewController = LaunchScreenViewController(nibName: "LaunchScreenViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Instead of this one ..

```
let viewController = LaunchScreenViewController()
```

**For Storyboard**

```
// global declaration 
let kApplicationDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

// use this extension
extension UIViewController{
    func changeStoryboardTo(){
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
        UIView.transition(with: (kApplicationDelegate.window)!,
                      duration:0.5,
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft,
                      animations: {
                        kApplicationDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
                        // do something
        }, completion:{
           finished in
            // competion code
        })*/

    }
}

extension UIStoryboard{
 func getControllerInstance(storyBoardName : String, identifire : String) -> UIViewController {
        let objStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = objStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifire)
    return vc
    }
}
```

*Calling*

```
_ = UIStoryboard().getControllerInstance(storyBoardName: "yourStoryboardName", identifire: "yourViewControllerIdentifire").changeStoryboardTo()
```

Comment: are you using xib or storyboard.

Comment: i use storyboard

Comment: @vaibhav - the ?'er want to load the launchscreen or call the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

Comment: Yes error is gone, but i got again same error "Use of unresolved identifier 'LaunchScreenViewController'"

Comment: have you given the identifier to your `viewController` inside the storyboard you are using ..

Answer (score -1):

If you are using storyboard and already have set viewcontroller identifier for the particular viewcontroller

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreenStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWith(identifier: "LaunchScreenViewController") as! LaunchScreenViewController
```

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'LaunchScreenViewController'

Comment: Do you really have any class called LaunchScreenViewController in your project. Please check for typos.

Comment: the ?'er want to load the launchscreen or call the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*